# sql query based on given set of values that need to be satisfied

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I need an postgresql query that returns me the id's of the businesses.

### Quick table setup:

businesses contains 0 or more cards, cards contains 0 or more sections, sections contains 0 or more products, products contains 0 or more tags.

### The problem

The query I need is for the following situation:
The user passes in a list of tag ids, which are associated with the products. The result should contain the businesses (ids) which include products that satisfy **all given tag ids**.

I created a query that works partially, as it returns the business id when at least one tag id matches.

```
select businesses.id  from businesses
left join cards on cards.id_business = businesses.id left join sections on sections.id_card = cards.id

left join products  on products.id_section = sections.id
left join product_tags  on product_tags.id_product = products.id
left join tags on tags.id = product_tags.id_tag

where product_tags.id_tag in (40, -1);
```

The tag with id -1 is not present in the table, I still get the business that contains the tag with id 40 as it has a product that contains this tag..

[Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp49X.png)

Comment: [mre] [ask] [Help] [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL.

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. So does your answer post. (I'm not saying this caused a problem, but since you are left joining where you could just inner join you are possibly confused.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I actually just had to get all entries where the idTag is in in the list of given ids and then group by tagid and having a count of the given ids (I modified the return value to include all columns instead of just the ids of the matching businesses):

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.businesses_for_tags(tag_ids integer[]) RETURNS SETOF public.businesses
LANGUAGE

 plpgsql
    AS $$
  BEGIN
    return query 
    select b.*
    from businesses b 
    left join cards c on c.id_business =b.id 
    left join sections s on c.id = s.id_card 
    left join products p on p.id_section = s.id 
    left join product_tags pt on pt.id_product = p.id
    left join tags t on t.id = pt.id_tag
    where pt.id_tag = any (tag_ids)
    group by b.id
    having count(distinct(pt.id_tag)) = array_length(tag_ids, 1) ;
    end;
$$;
```